# Getting Apache Commons Codec to work in Atom

Tags: java, maven, package

I am tring to import the apache commns codec into a java project in Atom using:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

But keep getting this:

```
error: package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
```

I have installed Maven on my computer, and installed the atom-maven package. Can someone please point me in the right direction to get this working. Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information. At the very least you should show the POM.

Comment: I would suggest to use a real IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ) for Java.. not Atom...(I assume by Atom https://atom.io/ ?)

Comment: Ye atom.io. I have it working in Netbeans now, i just like using Atom haha